# Is it possible to create a stream in ksqlDB to emit an ID that detects changes from 3 different tables that are joined together?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Is it possible to create a stream that detects changes on 3 different tables? For example, I have Table A which contains Ids for Table B and Table C. If I constructed my join query correctly. could I emit an event that contains Table A's id if there was a change in Table B or C?

**Table A**

- id
- b_id
- c_id
- field_abc
- field_xyz

**Table B**

- id
- foo

**Table C**

- id
- bar

I want a stream that will emit Table A id's if there is any changes in any of those 3 tables. Is this possible?

For example, if fields field_abc, foo, or bar were to change, I want Table A's id to be emitted to a stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar issue as what you're describing. Currently this isn't possible using streams or tables due to limitations on ksqlDB. We did find a way to achieve the same results though.

Our solution was to create a custom query with the connector that creates a 3-way joined table and combines the updated fields on the 3 tables.

```
CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR xyz_change WITH (
    'connector.class'          = '${v_connector_class}',
    'connection.url'           = '${v_connection_url}',
    'connection.user'          = '${v_connection_user}',
    'connection.password'      = '${v_connection_pass}',
    'topic.prefix'             = 'jdbc_abc_change',
    'mode'                     = 'timestamp+incrementing',
    'numeric.mapping'          = 'best_fit',
    'incrementing.column.name' = 'id',
    'timestamp.column.name'    = 'last_modified',
    'key'                      = 'id',
    'key.converter'            = '${v_converter_long}',
    'query'                    = 'select id, last_modified from(select a.id as id, GREATEST(a.last_modified, COALESCE(b.last_modified,from_unixtime(0)), COALESCE(c.last_modified,from_unixtime(0))) as last_modified  from aaa a  LEFT JOIN bbb b on a.fk_id = b.id  LEFT JOIN ccc c on a.fk_id = c.id ) sub'
);
```

With this you're able to create any streams/tables you need off of it.

Comment: This is exactly what we were needing. Just tested it and is detecting the change events perfectly. Thank you so much sir!